# Cartoon about a boy who could transform into a big blue bird and speak to animals

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, shape-shifter

I watched this cartoon when I was younger. It was about a boy who could transform into a big blue bird, speak to animals, and hear the song of the wind. His grandfather and sister had the same powers, but couldn't hear the song.

They had an evil uncle who could transform into a vulture, and had two warthogs as sidekicks. The grandpa could also do more magic like levitation.

The storyline is like this: The boy doesn't know that he and his family have powers. His family hides it from him. But on his 12th or 13th birthday, he finds that he can hear the animals speaking. He starts questioning his sanity until he finds his sister talking to a bird. He runs away into the forest where he sees the wind and hears its song. His evil uncle finds him with his warthogs. His sister comes to him and helps him escape. The family pack up their stuff and go away with the uncle in tow.

They reach their destination and the uncle is there too. He breaks the grandfather's wings and forces the boy to give him the song. The boy sings the song to him and he lets the grandpa go. The uncle then sings the song but it turns out that it had a wrong key. The earth opens up and swallows him with his warthogs. The boy then sings the song and it transforms the place into a paradise with waterfalls and green grass and everything.
The story is set in a semi arid desert of some kind.

That's all I remember. I don't remember the exact year but it was between 2012 and 2014. I watched it on "hosanna". Hosanna is a free to air channel on the "strong" decoder.

Comment: You have a nice start here but could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) and [edit] in some more details? For example, you say you watched this when you was younger, when was that?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Of course he watched it when he was younger :-)

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot, thanks for the tip. I have added some more information to help. But i don't really remember the exact year. Somewhere between 2012 and 2014

Answer (score 7):

It's *The Legend of the Secret Pass* (2010)!

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0765465/):

> The 'Legend of Secret Pass' takes place in the mountains of the South West and involves Thunderbirds of Indian mythology and an animal refuge of mystical proportions. An unlikely troop of animals and humans are caught up in a clash of ageless magic. In this moment of crisis, the barest chance to avoid cataclysm falls into the hands of an Indian boy, Manu.

### Trailer

Comment: Hi there! That's a very good catch - please post it as an answer to [that other question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/202185/98028) which is likely to be the same :) welcomed to the site!