# Movie about a boy who can’t turn into an eagle/falcon like his family

Tags: story-identification, movie

The movie I'm looking for is about a boy whose family can change into some kind of bird, but he can't. When he finally can change, he turns into a blue bird. He kinda looks like the bird in the movie *Zambezia*. I don’t remember a lot of the movie because it’s been an while since I saw it. At the end, there was like a big fight between the bad bird and the good bird.

I’m not sure but I think he did not live with his parents, but with an elder.

I saw it on TV, about 4/5 years ago. It was animated.

I know it's not a lot to go on, but I hope that someone can help me find this.

Comment: Did you see this on TV or in a theater? And how many years ago do you recall seeing it? Also, was this an animated movie or live-action?

Comment: I saw it on TV, about 4/5  years ago. It was an animated movie.

Comment: Probably the same one as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/197721/cartoon-about-a-boy-who-could-transform-into-a-big-blue-bird-and-speak-to-animal

Comment: @ruskel: If you can, check out the question I linked. Reading it might elicit further details from your memory.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots: Yes, that's the movie I mean!

Comment: Was it animated Western-style (so more cartoon) or rather Asian-style? (anime, then)

Answer (score 3):

It's [*The Legend of the Secret Pass*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0765465/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt)! (2010 not 2019 as IMDb claims).

> The 'Legend of Secret Pass' takes place in the mountains of the South West and involves Thunderbirds of Indian mythology and an animal refuge of mystical proportions. An unlikely troop of animals and humans are caught up in a clash of ageless magic. In this moment of crisis, the barest chance to avoid cataclysm falls into the hands of an Indian boy, Manu.

[This review](https://www.imdb.com/review/rw2798662/?ref_=tt_urv) mentions the "eagles" albeit just to criticise the films use of them.

> This film on American legend has mistakes and the makers have no idea what they are doing, they say they are Thunderbird's and turn into Eagles, but this is a mistake in its self a Thunderbird did exist when God created earth 6000 years ago and might even exist in remote places today & some tribes have even spotted them alive

Comment: You should provide details of the movie, and show how it matches the question.  There's some [guidance](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers, but the most important part is to add detail.  You could link to an article on Wikipedia, the movie's page on IMDB, or any other source you can find.

Comment: Note, I do see that it was suggested that you post your answer here as well as the other question.  But you still need a good enough post here for it to be understood as the answer to the question without referring to your previous answer.