# A story about a boy and a girl, the girl likes the boy who turned into a dove or pigeon

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime, short-film, studio-ghibli

I watched this when I was little, I don't remember it clearly, I really dont know how the movie goes until now but it somehow...touched my heart...I wanted to find this movie, Maybe it's an anime. I dont know  but I remember some of it. The boy indeed turned into a dove or something then flew away (I think thats how it ends) I remember cages and the color red, shining. It may be some curse making his transformation? The girl found out that he turned into a dove.
I can’t give any further details! I really wanted to find this movie, I just can’t seem to remember, it’s been bothering me.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Can you give us an idea what year you watched this?  "when I was little" doesn't help us very much. :)  You should also check out the [suggestions for anime-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/101407) and the more general [suggestions for story-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407).

Comment: Um, when were you a child?  The date when you saw the movie or episode would be the latest possible date for it to be made.  Where were you living when you saw it, what languages was it in, etc. etc.?  The more details you can remember and put in your question, the easier it will be for someone to answer it.

Comment: mio my son? lots if cages, birds that are children, and a stone heart that turns into a dove?

Comment: Are you certain this was a film and not a comic? https://www.gunnerkrigg.com/?p=255

Comment: Could it possibly be the same as the one described in this question? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/197721/cartoon-about-a-boy-who-could-transform-into-a-big-blue-bird-and-speak-to-animal